# What are the best types of apples to use in Charosset?

Tags: fruit, apples, jewish-cuisine, passover

What are the best type of apples to use when making Charosset for Passover?

I'm torn between something more neutral like Gala vs something tart (which might work well with the sweetness of the rest of the dish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through recipes suggests a variety of apples.  Gala showed up the most, with Fuji in second, and McIntosh and Delicious tied for last.

If you want to go with the "source" of the recipe for Charoset, though, you'll want a sweet apple.  The recipe has its [roots in Song of Solomon/Songs](http://newsweek.washingtonpost.com/onfaith/panelists/arthur_waskow/2009/04/passovers_r-rated_condiment.html), and the [verse that refers to the apples](http://www.hebrewoldtestament.com/B22C002.htm#V3) reads as:

> As the apple tree among the trees of the wood, so is my beloved among the sons. I sat down under his shadow with great delight, and his fruit was sweet to my taste.

So, for authenticity, go for a sweet apple, but Gala is the most mentioned apple in recipes online.

Answer (score 0):

I made mine with Empire apples this year and it was absolutely delicious!

Comment: If I remember correctly those are a reasonably sweet, crisp apple. Do you think that's a better fit than something tart?

Comment: Well I guess that all depends on what you're going for!  I like my charoses very sweet indeed.  And I also like it chunky. Those empires worked very well, rough cut with a knife and then mashed a bit.  I used walnuts and pecans, pan-toasted with a bit of butter and sugar.  Toasted whole and they come apart a bit during the mashing.  For spice I used powdered clove, nutmeg, and cinnamon. Some grape juice too to add sweetness, but not enough to make it wet. Delicious.

Answer (score -1):

We make ours with McIntosh and it's so yummy!

Comment: And what did you like about it? How do you think using McIntosh improved it in comparison with other apples?